# If the integral of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ along an interval symmetric to the origin is zero, is the function odd?

Tags: calculus, integration

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$We know that if a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is odd, then$$\int_{-a}^a f(x)\,\d x=0.$$ I'm wondering if the converse is true, and if not, if there are any counterexamples.

Thanks!

Edit: There was confusion about the quantifier for $a$, and I was also looking for continuity, even though I didn't say that in the question. So to clarify, I was wondering if the following statement was true or false:

Given a function $f \in C(I)$, if for some $a$ the integral$$\int_{-a}^af(x)\,\d x=0,$$ then $f$ must be odd.

Comment: Is your hypothesis that the integral is zero FOR ALL $a$? If so better amend the question.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, I was wrestling with that same thing but I think that's what OP does mean because the converse technically would be "If $\int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx = 0$ for all $a$ then..."

Comment: This question is more interesting with the stipulation that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true, simple counterexample is $f(x) = \cos x$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ since $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos x \,dx=0$.

Comment: The hypothesis of the converse would be $\int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx = 0$ for all $a$.

Comment: I think that's the only interpretation because the well known statement is "If $f$ is odd then $\int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx = 0$ for all values of $a$" and not "If $f$ is odd then $\int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx = 0$ for some fixed value of $a$."  Downvote isn't mine..

Comment: @tilper Its okay I don't care about downvote. You could say that the well known statement is that given $a>0$ we have if $f(x)$ is odd on $[-a,a]$, then integral is $0$, then opposite would be if integral is $0$ then $f(x)$ is odd ... I think it is really up to OP to decide what he meant. I will hide the answer until then...

Comment: Restored the answer as OP clarified the meaning is for some $a$, not for all $a$.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ with $\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=0$ for all $a>0$. In this case, the general answer is "no", and you can easily construct counterexamples by simply taking any odd function and changing it on a set of Lebesgue-measure zero to make it not odd. One such example has been given in JJR's answer for any fixed $a>0$.

However, if $f$ is known to have a classical primitive (i.e. a function $F$ that is differentiable everywhere with $F'=f$), then the answer is "yes" (note that every continuous function has such a primitive). In this case, assuming w.l.o.g. that $F(0)=0$, we have
\begin{align*}
F(a)=\int_0^a f(x)dx
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
0=\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=\int_{-a}^0f(x)dx+\int_0^af(x)dx=-F(-a)+F(a),
\end{align*}
which shows $F(-a)=F(a)$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$. Thus $F$ is even and hence $f$ is odd. (See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194062/derivative-of-an-even-function-is-odd-and-vice-versa) for more details on that last conclusion).

Answer (score 3):

$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll} 
1 & \text{ if }x\in[-a,a]\cap\mathbb{Q}\\
0 & \text{ else} \end{array}\right.$

Comment: @Doug M: No, it isn't.

Comment: Is this even integrable?

Comment: Yes it is integrable with integral 0

Comment: Not in Riemann-sense, but in Lebesgue sense it is integrable.

Comment: You can make it Riemann integrable just by making $f$ nonzero at only two points, say $\pm 1$.  It can take any values at those points as long as they are not negatives of each other and you will have a function that is not odd that integrates to zero over any interval, not just those symmetric around zero.

Comment: @Ross, how will making $f$ nonzero at only two points make $f$ Riemann-integrable?

Comment: @RossMillikan Or make $f$ nonzero at one point.

Comment: @tilper: A function is Riemann integrable iff it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere. This is clearly the case if $f$ is zero everywhere except at two points.

Comment: @tilper:  as long as there  is a finite number of discontinuities it is Riemann-integrable as you can make the width of the intervals containing the discontinuities as small as you want.

Comment: ohhhh I get it now.  At first I thought you meant take the $f$ that JJR gave and make *it* nonzero at two *additional* points.  The world makes sense again.  @RossMillikan

Comment: and CC @sranthrop

Answer (score 2):

*Counter-example (sketch):*

Consider the function, defined on $[-1,1]$ as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }\;0\le x<\frac12,\\
x-1&\text{if }\;\frac12< x\le 1,\\
0& \text{if }\;-1\le x<0.
\end{cases}$$

For a *continuous* function on $[-1,1]$, consider the function defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin (2\pi x)&\text{if }\;0\le x\le 1,\\
0& \text{if }\;-1\le x<0.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: This does not work, the integral over the interval $-\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}$ is not zero... (assuming the OP considers the statement to be for all $a \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$).

Comment: I didn't suppose it were true for all $a$, of course (and the O.P. does not specify it).

Comment: I would think the OP asks if the statement "$f$ is odd then for all $a$ $\int_{-a}^{a}f = 0$" is actually an equivalence...

Comment: I can't understand why people continues to write that the statement is "for all $\;a\;$ ". The title is very precise: "...along **an** interval symmetric to..." ! This counter example works just fine. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio, the title is precise but, as is common on this site (although usually not this subtle), the question is different.  OP mentions the "well known" fact that "If a function $f$ is odd then $\int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx = 0$."  Those who know this know that it's true for all $a$.  So the converse, that OP specifically asks about in the question (thus subtly contradicting the title), is "If $\int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx = 0$ for all $a$, then $f$ is odd"

Comment: And the "an" in the title could be a typo and the word "any" was meant to be there.  This is really just a classic case of answering the title vs. answering the post.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for the counterexample, I can definitely see how this works. Unfortunately I didn't mention that I was looking for a continuous function (I've editted the question) but I think I can find a counterexample based on your piecewise function.

Comment: @ChrisWong: I've added a very  simple example with a continuous function.