# If g is an odd function and g'(5) = 3, what is the value of g'(−5)? g'(−5) =?

Tags: calculus

If g is an odd function and  g'(5) = 3,  what is the value of  g'(−5)?   g'(−5) = ?
 We haven't really talked about this material in class so I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: What's the definition of an odd function? How about an even function? What happens when you take the derivative?

Comment: Can you answer this question in the case where $g(x)=3x$?

Comment: @Aimee Wheeler If you're satisfied with my answer, remember you can click the green tick (below the voting buttons) to accept an answer.

Answer (score 5):

We know that the derivative of an odd function is an even function ([according to this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194062/derivative-of-an-even-function-is-odd-and-vice-versa)). Since by definition, an even function has $f(-x) = f(x)$, then if $g'(5) = 3$, what is $g'(-5)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $g$ be an odd function:

1)$g(x) = - g(-x)$.

Example: $G(x) = x^3 = - G(-x)$.

2)$g'(x) = g'(-x)$ (Chain rule).

Note: $g'(x)$ is an even fct.

Example: $G'(x) = 3x^2 = G'(-x)$.

Your example:

$g'(5) = g'(-5)=3$.