# How can I prove that $f′(x) = f ′ (- x)$

Tags: functions

Prove that if $f$ is an odd function, then $f ′ (x) = f ′ (- x)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivative of an even function is odd and vice versa](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194062/derivative-of-an-even-function-is-odd-and-vice-versa)

Comment: If f is odd -f(x)=f(-x)

Comment: @uhhhhidk no, that is if $f$ is even.

Comment: @Dunkelheit -f(x)=f(-x) is the definition of an odd function

Comment: @uhhhhidk That pencil on the right of your comment means that it was edited, it's not a shame to say that one can make mistakes (even just typo).

Comment: @Dunkelheit I admit I typed that in at first but you commented after I changed it so I assumed you misread it or something, it might’ve taken longer than I expected

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is odd then $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$; now you can take the derivative (because $f$ must be at least derivable or this question has no sense) of both sides and get (for the chain rule)
$$-f'(-x)=-f'(x)\Rightarrow f'(-x)=f'(x)$$